# NameError: name 'game' is not defined

Tags: machine-learning, inteligencia-artificial

buenasss

tengo el siguiente codigo :

```
def play(rounds=5000, max_life=3, discount_factor = 0.1, learning_rate = 0.1,
     ratio_explotacion=0.9,learner=None, game=None, animate=False):

if game is None:
    game = PongEnvironment(max_life=max_life, movimiento_px = 3)
    
if learner is None:
    print("Begin new Train!")
    learner = PongAgent(discount_factor = discount_factor,learning_rate = learning_rate, ratio_explotacion= ratio_explotacion)

max_points= -9999
first_max_reached = 0
total_rw=0
steps=[]

for played_games in range(0, rounds):
    state = game.reset()
    reward, done = None, None
    
    itera=0
    while (done != True) and (itera < 3000 and game.total_reward<=1000):
        old_state = np.array(state)
        next_action = learner.get_next_step(state, game)
        state, reward, done = game.step(next_action, animate=animate)
        if rounds > 1:
            learner.update(game, old_state, next_action, reward, state, done)
        itera+=1
    
    steps.append(itera)
    
    total_rw+=game.total_reward
    if game.total_reward > max_points:
        max_points=game.total_reward
        first_max_reached = played_games
    
    if played_games %500==0 and played_games >1 and not animate:
        print("-- Partidas[", played_games, "] Avg.Puntos[", int(total_rw/played_games),"]  AVG Steps[", int(np.array(steps).mean()), "] Max Score[", max_points,"]")
            
if played_games > 1:
    print('Partidas[',played_games,'] Avg.Puntos[',int(total_rw/played_games),'] Max score[', max_points,'] en partida[',first_max_reached,']')
    
#learner.print_policy()
return learner, game
learner, game = play(rounds=5000, discount_factor = 0.2, learning_rate = 0.1, ratio_explotacion=0.85)
```

**En esta ultima linea tengo el error de NameError: name 'game' is not defined**
Puede ser que tenga un error de sangria en el codigo? ya que game esta definido en
game = PongEnvironment(max_life=max_life, movimiento_px = 3)

Cualquier ayuda desde ya muchas gracias
Saludos

Comment: Justo antes de definir `game` si no está definido... compruebas si `game` está sin definir! `if game is None:`... donde has declarado game? Debajo de esa comprobación, verdad? Entonces en esa comprobación, `game` todavía no existe, de ahí el error!

Comment: Condicione como comentario  #if game is None:  y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Si tienes la sangría tal cual la has puesto aquí, entonces si, está mal. Todo lo que va después del `def` debería ir indentado un paso a la derecha. El problema es que muchas veces cuando copiais y pegais el código en SO no respetais las sangrías tal cual las teneis, así que es muy difícil saber si es por eso o no. Si la tienes igual que en la pregunta, pon todo desde el primer hasta el return un nivel más hacia la derecha y se solucionará el problema. Si no la tienes así, por favor edita la pregunta y pon la sangría tal cual la tienes, porque efectivamente, aquí no está bien indentado

Answer (score 0):

Python delimita bloques usando tabulaciones. Si todo lo que hay entre `def play` y `return` va dentro de la función `play` deberías tabularlo.

```py
def play(rounds=5000, max_life=3, discount_factor = 0.1, learning_rate = 0.1,
     ratio_explotacion=0.9,learner=None, game=None, animate=False):

    if game is None:
        game = PongEnvironment(max_life=max_life, movimiento_px = 3)
        
    if learner is None:
        print("Begin new Train!")
        learner = PongAgent(discount_factor = discount_factor,learning_rate = learning_rate, ratio_explotacion= ratio_explotacion)

    max_points= -9999
    first_max_reached = 0
    total_rw=0
    steps=[]

    for played_games in range(0, rounds):
        state = game.reset()
        reward, done = None, None
        
        itera=0
        while (done != True) and (itera < 3000 and game.total_reward<=1000):
            old_state = np.array(state)
            next_action = learner.get_next_step(state, game)
            state, reward, done = game.step(next_action, animate=animate)
            if rounds > 1:
                learner.update(game, old_state, next_action, reward, state, done)
            itera+=1
        
        steps.append(itera)
        
        total_rw+=game.total_reward
        if game.total_reward > max_points:
            max_points=game.total_reward
            first_max_reached = played_games
        
        if played_games %500==0 and played_games >1 and not animate:
            print("-- Partidas[", played_games, "] Avg.Puntos[", int(total_rw/played_games),"]  AVG Steps[", int(np.array(steps).mean()), "] Max Score[", max_points,"]")
                
    if played_games > 1:
        print('Partidas[',played_games,'] Avg.Puntos[',int(total_rw/played_games),'] Max score[', max_points,'] en partida[',first_max_reached,']')
        
    #learner.print_policy()
    return learner, game

learner, game = play(rounds=5000, discount_factor = 0.2, learning_rate = 0.1, ratio_explotacion=0.85)
```